# Invalid JSON was returned from the route , Laravel 8 Unit Testing

Tags: php, laravel, api, unit-testing

I am very new to testing in Laravel, I'm working in laravel 8, the function that I want to test is :

When I run my test I get this error:

```
1) Tests\Unit\appTest\HttpTest\ControllersTest\OrderControllerTest::testStore
Invalid JSON was returned from the route.
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two scenarios

1. In your controller you can do

```
return response()->json([
     'order' => $newOrder,
     'status' => ($request->doValidate) ? 'pend' : 'draft'
]);
```

and your test case will be the same

2. In your controller you can do

```
return response()->json($newOrder);
// or
return $newOrder;
```

and in your test case you will do

```
public function testStore()
{
    Sanctum::actingAs($this->user, ['*']);
    $response = $this->postJson(action('OrderController@store'), [
        'doAssigned' => false,
        'doValidate' => false,
    ]);

    $response->assertJsonFragment([
        'status' => 'draft'
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help , but I'm still confused , I still get the same error even after making the changes .  **Tests\Unit\appTest\HttpTest\ControllersTest\OrderControllerTest::testStore
Invalid JSON was returned from the route**

Comment: Did you use `return response()->json($newOrder);` and `dd($newOrder);` before returning it and paste the result in your question.

Comment: Yes I used the `return response()->json($newOrder); ` and `dd($newOrder);` bit I still get the same error

Comment: I suppose that your code throws error somewhere so you need to do `$response = $this->postJson(action('OrderController@store'), [
        'doAssigned' => false,
        'doValidate' => false,
    ])->dump();` and see what result do you got.